# How to get value from EditText on current tab inside TabHost

Tags: android, get, android-edittext, android-tabhost

I have tabhost, and it has 4 tabs : Detail, Material, Leg, Other Photo. I have successfully to display all of them. And now my question is how to get text value from EditText on Detail tabs , when I clicked the menu on right corner (on onOptionsItemSelected)? Here is my code :

```
public class ViewDetailItem extends TabActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_detail_item);
        Global.ViewDetailItem=this;

        Bundle param=getIntent().getExtras();
        String tseparate=(String) param.get("tseparate");
        String tgroup=(String) param.get("tgroup");
        String titemcode=(String) param.get("titemcode");

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab        

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DetailTab.class);
        intent.putExtra("titemcode", titemcode);
        intent.putExtra("tseparate", tseparate);
        intent.putExtra("tgroup", tgroup);        
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("detail").setIndicator("Detail Item",res.getDrawable(R.layout.activity_tab_detail)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MaterialTab.class);
        intent.putExtra("titemcode", titemcode);
        intent.putExtra("tseparate", tseparate);
        intent.putExtra("tgroup", tgroup); 
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("material").setIndicator("Mat Color",res.getDrawable(R.layout.activity_tab_materialcolor)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, LegTab.class);
        intent.putExtra("titemcode", titemcode);
        intent.putExtra("tseparate", tseparate);
        intent.putExtra("tgroup", tgroup);         
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("leg").setIndicator("Leg Color",res.getDrawable(R.layout.activity_tab_legcolor)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);  

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, OtherPhotoTab.class);
        intent.putExtra("titemcode", titemcode);
        intent.putExtra("tseparate", tseparate);
        intent.putExtra("tgroup", tgroup);         
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("other").setIndicator("Other Photos",res.getDrawable(R.layout.activity_tab_legcolor)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);  

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menudetailitem, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {               
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.menuaddtocontainer:   
                // here is the code
                // how to get value from edittext (id: EdtQty)on DetailTab
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this make the function return your text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319648/android-how-to-call-function-of-activity-inside-of-tab-from-the-tabhost

Comment: If you need more help, tell me, I will create an answer with code

Comment: What errors do you got?

Comment: wait, I think that I make little mistake, let me try once again

Comment: I just applied with the answer number 1, and here my source code : http://pastebin.com/gsU1LYY5

Comment: Ok, but on which code line do you get an error? + what kind of error?